# How can i access array of objects which is my instance variable from a non static method?

Tags: java, arrays, object

My program is giving me null pointer even if my constructor has instantiated the array of object. Why am I getting the exception?
Here is my code: when the main method runs the comparison line, it gives me a null pointer exception. Can I not access my objects this way?

```
class MPLTest{
int n;
MPL []std;
MPLTest(){
    System.out.println("Enter number of Standards: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    n=in.nextInt();
    MPL []std = new MPL[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students for standard "+(i+1));
        std[i]=new MPL(i+1,in.nextInt());
    }

}
public static void main(String [] args){

    MPLTest test = new MPLTest();
    System.out.println("The standard scoring the highest total marks is "+test.findBestClass());

}
int findBestClass(){
    int best=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(std[i].findTotal()>std[best].findTotal()) //the exception is here
            best=i;
    }
    return best+1;
}
```

}

Comment: This line MPL []std = new MPL[n]; should be std = new MPL[n];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` because the **global instance array** is not initialized in the constructor. You have declared `std[]` in the class but in the constructor, you have declared a **new** array, which is a **local** array, of type `MPL`. To initialize the instance array, replace the line

```
MPL[] std = new MPL[n]; //creates a local variable
```

with

```
std = new MPL[n]; //points to the global variable
```

This is similar to using the instance variable `int n`. In the constructor, you **don't** write

```
int n = in.nextInt();
```

but

```
n = in.nextInt();
```

because `n` is already declared. Initialize the array in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

```java
→   MPL []std;
    MPLTest(){
        System.out.println("Enter number of Standards: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n=in.nextInt();
→       MPL []std = new MPL[n];
```

This is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Your `std` inside the block is a local variable and it shadows a similarly named, but distinct, field named `std`.

Comment: Who downvoted this? There's a better answer with no votes and a worse answer (comment) with upvote. What's the deal?